# Plural possessives of words not ending in s

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

So I know the difference between "the dog's owner" and "the dogs' owner," but I'm wondering how to write the possessive for a word like maxima. Is it as easy as "the maxima's positions" or is there some other weird English exception?

Thanks.

Comment: It's *"the maxima's positions"*, although you can always use *"the positions of the maxima"* instead. (But don't do this with people: it should be *"John's car"* and not *"the car of John"*. The second one isn't strictly wrong, but it is very unusual in English today.)

Answer (score 2):

It is just like "the men's house".